# Spring security login behind reverse proxy

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, proxy

I have my Spring application developed with Spring MVC 4 and ThymeLeaf.
I have secured it with Spring Security 3.
If I have direct access, everything is fine, but if I want to create a Reverse Proxy to manage the connection, Spring Security doesn't works.

My Spring Security configuration is:

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
.formLogin().loginPage("/html/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/html/index", true).permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/html/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/html/login?logout").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/html/res/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/html").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/html/**").authenticated();
```

The csrf is disabled because it doesn't works with the reverse proxy.
My reverse proxy code on Apache 2.4 with mod_proxy_http is

```
ServerName example.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/html/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/html/
```

I can see the login page, but when i click on "login", instead of having http://example.com/index, i have http://example.com/myapp/html/.
I think is a problem related to the absolute path that Spring Security requires, but I don't know how to solve this.

**UPDATE**
I made it works with a workaround... I added this to my apache site conf file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/myapp/html/(.*)$ /$1 [PT]
```

So it removes the duplicate piece of the address. But I don't like this.
My login page is:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="modal-header" align="center">
        <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" th:src="@{res/img/logo200x200.png}">
    </div>
    <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{login}" method="post">

        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Failed to login.
            <div th:if="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
              Reason: <span th:text="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>

        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <!--
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
        -->
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: http.authorizeRequests().formLogin().loginPage("/html/login").failureUrl("/html/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/html/index", true).permitAll()


Please try this may be its work for you because in my system its work for me

Comment: @RaviKavaiya I can't see the difference

Comment: Yes @zuno, nothing different currently i'm using same as per you have and its work for me

Comment: Add your login page.

Comment: see you did mistake here  
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/> 
**you need to put like this**
<input type="hidden" th.name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th.value="${_csrf.token}"/>